# Gráficos com PHP

Tags: php, chartjs

Estou com dificuldades para gerar gráficos usando dados vindos do banco.

Tenho uma consulta no banco que gera como resultado um array. (Segue abaixo)

```html
<?php
            require_once './setaqueryDash.php';
            require_once './conecta.php';
            $resultado = ibase_query($CONEXAO_TERM, QueryDashDesafios(substr($loja_selecionada, 0,3),$data_dash));//executa query e armazena o resultado em um array


             while ($dash1 = ibase_fetch_row($resultado)){
                $dataPoints[] = ['y' => $dash1['0'],
                                 'label'  => $dash1['1']
                                ]; 
            }
?>
```

Ja testei e os dados desse array estão corretos, são os dados que quero mesmo...

Minha dúvida é **como fazer esses dados serem os do Gráfico**. Segue código da geração do gráfico:

```html
<script>
  var MONTHS = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  var color = Chart.helpers.color;
  var horizontalBarChartData = {
   labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'], //exemplo
//                        labels: "aqui gostaria dos meus dados"
   datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset 1',
    backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
    borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
    borderWidth: 1,
//                              data: "aqui gostaria dos meus dados",
    data: [
     125000,
     125000,
     125000,
     125000,
     125000,
     125000,
     125000
    ] // como ta no exemplo
   }]

  };
```

Nesse caso eu gostaria de trazer os Labels e os Dados vindos do array.

Obrigado...

Comment: Na verdade estou na dúvida se posso usar algo dessa forma....

Answer (score 0):

Se puder utilizar a API da google,fica bem simples

Basta fazer um select aos dados que quer :

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(dados1) FROM Table WHERE x='y' "
$result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       //codigo js do google charts onde associa o valor a row(não está todo)
       echo "<script> function drawChart1() {
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Mês', ' Vendas'],
      ['Janeiro ',  ".$row['y']."]);";
    echo "var options = {
                    title: 'Titulo ',
                    curveType: 'function',
                    legend: { position: 'bottom' }"
    echo" var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart2'));

    chart.draw(data, options);"
    }
  else{ echo "falhou"
      }
```

> Google Charts

Deixo aqui o link atual:

https://developers.google.com/chart/  -11/01/2018 12:30 Pt-pt

Comment: To usando o https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/ (chartjs),  é meio complicado para ajustar os gráficos, ainda mais quando tem que colocar mais de um gráfico na tela, mas aos pouco to conseguindo. Valeu pela dica.